# Is it possible to use Interpreter Mode packaging for AIR iOS Enterprise in-house distribution?

Tags: ios, air, packaging

I have a Flash Builder project that loads an external SWF (into the current ApplicationDomain). As a result, even though I'm compiling using AIR SDK 3.9, I'm still getting strange errors that I cannot seem to resolve.

I have been testing and distributing using the final Distribution provisioning file in Interpreted (Fast Packaging) Mode, and things are working great (the app is not particularly complex).

What are the risks when using Enterprise In-House distribution with apps packaged in Interpreted Mode? I have no intention of bringing this app to the App Store.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My own experience, a quarter after writing this question, is that **YES** it is possible to distribute an IPA created using Interpreted (Fast Packaging) mode using Enterprise In-House distribution. I have successfully completed such a project and the client is using it without issue.